# How to retrieve organizational unit for current login user from G Suite in chrome extension/app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-accounts, google-workspace, google-directory-api

User was managed by G Suite, I login chrome book with the user, in a chrome extension/app, I can get the email/ID of current login user, how can I retrieve organizational unit info for current user?

I tried googleapis which I found cannot be used in chrome extension.

edit:

I don't want the end user view the login page, so I used google service account  with Domain-wide delegation enabled; I also created a G Suite user which only have get user permission, with Nodejs googleapis and service account, I can retrieve org unit for user who has no user permission, [Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) is about how to use the service account. BUT this will not work in my extension.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you request an ID token, consider using the hd parameter [1].
You could also try to use the cloud organizations search API [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#id_token-hd
[2] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/organizations/search#body.request_body.FIELDS.filter